# Is there anything thing like pastescript without the paste part?

Tags: python, automated-tests, build-automation, paste, buildout

I am looking for a simple lib/tool like paster that I can easily create custom commands without having anything to do with paste itself. I am looking to create a helper tool like paster or manage.py to do various tasks like build (maybe using buildout), build documentation and run scripts/tests for a non-web/non-wsgi based project. (that's why I don't want anything that needs paste)

Any suggestions on a tool? Does my approach sound reasonable?

Comment: you can write commands for paste that have nothing to do with wsgi/web i've done it plenty. But if you are just looking for something to author subcommands and handle command line parameters why not just use argparse http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html and then dispatch to your commands however you like?

Answer (score 0):

Often I use [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) as my general purpose project janitor. Usually I automate the following tasks with Fabric:

- generate documentation
- run tests
- make releases

Initially Fabric has been developed to ease the automation/scripting of commands to run on remote hosts using SSH. However, Fabric is also an excellent tool to automate local project management related tasks.

Fabric commands are plain Python functions within a so called *fabfile*. You don't need to know much about Fabric to get started. Here's a simple `fabfile.py`:

```
from fabric.api import local

def tests():
    """Run the test suite."""
    ...

def release(version):
    """Make a relase."""
    tests()
    local("hg tag %s" % version)
    ...
```

which may be used like that:

```
$ fab -l
Available commands:

    release  Make a relase.
    tests    Run the test suite.

$ fab release:version=0.1
...
[localhost] local: hg tag 0.1
...
```

Concerning buildout, just add this part to your `buildout.cfg` and Fabric is ready to use at `bin/fab`:

```
[fabric]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    <things-you-need-in-your-fabfile>
    fabric
```